# Automating results

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python. I would like to write a program which can collect information from multiple excel and pdf documents to output that in one single excel document to show similarities and differences between the documents . Is this possible ? If so, how and where would I start writing such a programme in python? Thanks

I haven’t tried anything yet

Comment: Reading an excel file and a pdf file is very different. Pandas can natively read and write an excel file (xls,xlsx,csv) and libraries like PyPDF2 can read PDF files.

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow would it possible for you to elaborate with an example code on how I can get started please ?

Comment: It really depends on what type of data you are trying to digest. Saying "information from multiple excel/pdf files" could be anything especially a pdf. I would google "python pandas read excel" and "python pypdf2 example" or edit your post with example input / expected output.